# Default nullpointexception checker for a for each loop

Tags: java, foreach, nullpointerexception

Is there a default nullpointerexception checker for a for each loop?

For example, right now I am writing a for each loop that can loop my list.  But in order to test that the list is not null, I must test it explicitly.

Can my code be simplified by some default nullpointerexception checker that I am not aware of?  This way I dont have to create an if statement and check for null manually.

My current code:

```
if (myList != null) {
     for (String item : myList) {
          ...;
          ...;
     }
}
```

Comment: What would that "checker" do if it turns out to be null?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth throws the nullpointerexception on its own without breaking the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means - how is that different to just not checking at all?

Comment: `for (String item : MoreObjects.firstNonNull(myList, Collections.emptyList()))`, using Guava.

Comment: @weston really? That's not what the current code does.

Comment: @weston not in terms of what it does. Whether you use `myList != null ? myList : Collections.emptyList()` or the Guava `MoreObjects.firstNonNull`, it's checking the list reference, not checking per element.

Comment: @weston yep, that's why I changed it to one without the explicit null check.

Comment: @AndyTurner sorry I missunderstood Q, looks like a good answer, but then they **do** want the NPE, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Groovy's default method `.each` would automatically "skip" iterating over each element of a null collection object without the dreaded NPE appearing.  Groovy also has the "Elvis operator" `?:` which is precisely a shorthand way to provide a sensible default if/when the tested object is null.  But since OP asked about Java only, this is a comment and not an answer.  In pure java there really isn't an automatic way to hide or work around explicitly testing objects for null before calling methods on those objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use Java 8 stream API to filter out the nulls:

```
myList.stream()
   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
   .forEach(elem -> doSomething(elem));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check if the items inside `ArrayList` are `NULL` or not. We know that `ArrayList` allows `NULL` to be added. So, you can do this to test it:

```
for (String item : myList) {
    if (item != null){
      ...;
      ...;
    }
}
```

If you also want to make sure that the list itself is not `NULL` and the elements in the `ArrayList` are also not `NULL`, then you do this:

```
if (myList != null) {
   for (String item : myList) {
       if (item != null) {
          ...;
          ...;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That your list is not null is not a guaranty that the object in it are not...

Unfortunately, you will need to check that too

```
if (myList != null) {
     for (String item : myList) {
         if (item != null) {
              ...;
              ...;
         }
     }
}
```